# ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(15,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ServiceName'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular7

I'm new to angular and trying to learn each step by step, I have one service and need to make use it in Component but getting the above error.

1. created a app using angular cli `ng new appName`
2. created a component using `ng g c comp-name`
3. created a service using `ng g s service-name`
4. When I add the service name in `app.module.ts` inside Providers:['service-name']. Getting the below error after building the code using `ng build || ng serve`

   ```
   Hash: 31c1abeb694df29adcbe
   ```

   Time: 8299ms
   chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 637 bytes [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 93.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
   chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
   chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]

   ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(15,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ServiceOneService'.

Component CLASS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ServiceOneService} from "../service-one.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'comp-one',
  templateUrl: './comp-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comp-one.component.css']
})
export class CompOneComponent implements OnInit {

  list;
  constructor(service: ServiceOneService) {
    this.list = service.getList();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceOneService {

  getList() {
    return ["List Item 1","List Item 2","List Item 3","List Item 4"];
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CompOneComponent } from './comp-one/comp-one.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CompOneComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ServiceOneService], `// getting error here.`
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have these installed on my machine.

```
Npm : 6.1.0
Node : v8.9.4
Angular Version : "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
Typescript : Version 3.1.1
```

Can someone please help me here what is wrong in importing or adding service to component.

Comment: You simply don’t have it imported in that file. That being said, you don’t need to provide it because you using providedIn already on that service.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for your answer, I see providerIn : 'root', so the reason no need to add one more time in app.module.ts inside provider :[], hope I understood correctly. Its working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import ServiceOneService in app.module.ts

```
import {ServiceOneService} from "../service-one.service";
```

Comment: This worked for me @Sajeethara, but during the tutorial they didnt mention anywhere in the Doc that I have to import.

Comment: It should automatically get imported with the Ng command probably you have missed something. Mark if the answer helped

Comment: In component it is automatically imported but in app.module.ts when i add the service inside providers:[] it is not imported automatically, that caused error.